# connected sets dont have subsets that are both open and closed

Tags: general-topology

My problem states the following:

A topological space $X$ is connected if and only if there are no nonempty proper subsets of $X$ that are both open and closed in $X$.

Here is my proof:

Since the theorem is if and only if statement, we must prove it in both directions.

($\Rightarrow$) Let $X$ be a connected topological space and for the sake of contradiction, suppose $U$ is an open and closed proper subset of $X$. Because $U$ is open, nonempty and proper subset of $X$, it must be the case that $X-U$ is closed and likewise nonempty and proper subset of $X$; because $U$ is closed, it follows that $X-U$ is open. But now we have that $U \cup (X-U) = X$, $U \cap (X-U) = \emptyset$ and $U$, $X-U$ are open, nonempty subsets of $X$, which means that $X$ is not connected. This is a contradiction, because we assumed $X$ to be connected; therefore, it must be the case that if $X$ is connected, then there are no nonempty proper subsets of $X$ that are both open and closed in $X$.

($\Leftarrow$) We will prove this direction by contrapositive method.

Let $X$ be a topological space and suppose that $A$ is a nonempty proper subset of $X$ that is both open and closed in $X$. But since $A$ is open, it must be the case that the complement of $A$, i.e. $X-A$ is closed; similarly, since $A$ is closed, $X-A$ must be open. Also, since $A$ is a nonempty proper subset of $X$, it follows that so is $X-A$. Observe, that $A \cap (X-A) = \emptyset$, and $A \cup (X-A) = X$. So now we have that both, $A$ and $X-A$ are open nonempty proper subsets of $X$ that are disjoint and $A \cup (X-A) = X$. Hence, it must be the case that $X$ is not connected.

My question is: Both directions look almost identical, is this ok, or shall I work on this in some another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first implication is right, the second part of the proof shows exactly the same. Notice that proving that there exists a closed and open subset in X implies not-connectedness is equivalent to proving that connected spaces don't have subsets that are closed and open at the same time.

What you should do is assume you have no subsets closed and open at the same time and prove that the space is connected or, for a contradiction, assume the space is not connected and let this contradict the fact that there are no subsets closed and open at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You are proving the same implication twice! In the second part you have to assume that $X$ is not connected and prove that you can find a  set (not empty, not equal to $X$) that is both open and closed . Since $X$ is not connected we can write $X =A \cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are nonempty disjoint open sets. Verify that $B=A^{c}$ and conclude that $A$ is open and closed and $A$ is not empty, not equal to $X$.